# How to turn of "add field" permission for all pointers

Tags: parse-platform

Parse.com docs suggest us to always turn off "add field" permission for all of classes when we submit your app to the public.

This is correct, but this config is not possible when there is pointer set to _User. The imagem bellow shows that Parse.com Browser don`t let us do that. So, how to resolve this issue.

[Image from parse.com browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Moqf9.png)

Comment: Interesting find. I use ACLs instead of CLPs for everything outside of disabling 'add field', so I hadn't seen this before. I just tested this out using both the old and new dashboards with the same results. I would guess that this is a bug and should be reported to the Parse team. In the meantime, the only other option appears to be using ACLs to restrict read/write/update and then use the public CLP to disable add field

Comment: It seems that this issue will not be resolved right now, Facebook is closing its doors [Facebook Shutters Its Developer Platform, Parse](http://recode.net/2016/01/28/facebook-shutters-its-developer-platform-parse/)

Comment: I'd still report it if you haven't yet. Parse will also be releasing an open-sourced version of their dashboard and data browser, hopefully they also polish off whatever remaining bugs they can before then. [source: Fosco](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10991729)